# SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot pop something in a json when the bot leaves a guild, When the bot joins a guild, I have it log the guild id and the guild's owner's id in a json file. That works fine, but when I make it delete it when the bot leaves that guild, I get the error `SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call`

My code is:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open('serverlist.json', 'r') as f:
        serverlist = json.load(f)

    serverlist.pop(str(guild.id)) = str(guild.owner.id)

    with open('serverlist.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(serverlist, f, indent=4)
```

My JSON file:

```py
{
    "836412234673815590": "467715040087244800",
    "834914066040356934": "467715040087244800"
}
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with `serverlist.pop(str(guild.id)) = str(guild.owner.id)`? I get the pop part, but what are you expecting to assign?

Comment: The syntax error is correct; that line of code makes no sense whatsoever. What are you trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Whenever the bot leaves a guild, it will find the line with the guild and owner info in the json file and delete it. `pop` makes it actually delete it if im correct.

Comment: Yes, that all makes sense. What does the `= str(guild.owner.id)` part mean though?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I just answered it, your right, I don't need that

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I just figured it out on my own. I don't need `= str(guild.owner.id)`! All i need to do is delete the guild id and the owner id will just delete with it. I have this same setup when my bot deletes the custom server prefix in a json file when the bot leaves that server.